# Django - Choices for Models

Tags: django, django-models, multiple-choice

I have been searching and looking through docs, but I want to ask and confirm for the best solution here.

Trying to define model choices.

1. 'yes, no and not sure' choice From Radio Select
2. How would I define for Multiple Choices

Simple Example:
In my models.py, I have

```
class Property(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Feature(models.Model):
    YES_CHOICES = (       # example of 1, there can be only one selection
        ('YES', 'Yes'),
        ('NO', 'No'),
        ('NOT_SURE', 'Not Sure')
    )
    PARKING_CHOICES = (    # example of 2, there can be multiple selections
        ('GARAGE', 'Garage'),
        ('STREET', 'Street'),
        ('PRIVATE_LOT', 'Private Lot'),
        ('VALET', 'Valet'),
    )

    nearby_school = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=YES_CHOICES)
    parking_options = models. MultipleChoiceField(choices=PARKING_CHOICES)

class PropertyFeature(models.Model)
    property = models.ForeignKey(Property)
    feature = models.ForeignKey(Feature)
    ...
```

Are those best ways to do it?

1. Should I use NullBooleanField instead for yes, no , not sure question?
2. Is that a correct way for defining and storing for multiple choice answers? Sometimes, I see people using manytomany objects.

Just want to use the most efficient and the easiest method offered from Django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `NullBoolean` is appropriate, but if there are more options that don't fit the profile of `NullBoolean`, I'm in favor of `IntegerField` for readability and consistency across options.

`Null` could intuitively mean `n/a`, but as you add more single choice questions, I think it's even more intuitive to use an `IntegerField` mapped to static variables.

Also for this type of scenario where the user will probably filter properties based on these features, it's useful not to have to special case Null in your dynamic query.

Example:

```
...filter(Q(nearby_school__isnull=True) | Q(nearby_school='NO')),
    other_choice='SOME_CHOICE')
# vs
...filter(Q(nearby_school=Feature.NOT_SURE) | Q(nearby_school=Feature.NO)), 
    other_choice=Feature.SOME_CHOICE)
```

This ancient post still serves as a great reference: 
http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/nov/02/handle-choices-right-way/

```
class Feature(models.Model):
    YES = 0
    NO = 1
    NOT_SURE = 2
    SOMETIMES = 3
    YES_CHOICES = ( 
        (YES, 'Yes'),
        (NO, 'No'),
        (NOT_SURE, 'Not Sure'),
        (SOMETIMES, 'Sometimes'), # extensible.
    )
```

As for a multiple choice field, I do think using a m2m field is the easiest/best way.

You could set up your `forms.MultipleChoiceField` to store data as a comma separated field & display appropriately, but the fact that you can query the m2m field easily is a huge benefit + it works right out of the box with `ModelMultipleChoiceField`.

Comment: Aren't you able to filter multiplechoicefields with [icontains](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#icontains)?

Comment: I suppose yeah. You could set up '01', '02', to set up 100 options!

Comment: Thank you Yuji for clear answer. One more question, If I have many multichoices items.. say  like 15 different multichoice items, then I would need 15 extra manytomany relationships. Is that okay for performance?

Answer (score 5):

18 months or so later, there is now a better way of dealing with `choices` in Django; [Łukasz Langa's `dj.choices`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/dj.choices/). An example of its use, from the [blog post introducing the project](http://lukasz.langa.pl/2/upgrading-choices-machinery-django/):

```
from dj.choices import Choices, Choice

class Gender(Choices):
    male = Choice("male")
    female = Choice("female")
    not_specified = Choice("not specified")

class User(models.Model):
    gender = models.IntegerField(choices=Gender(),
            default=Gender.not_specified.id)

    def greet(self):
        gender = Gender.from_id(self.gender)
        if gender == Gender.male:
            return 'Hi, boy.'
        elif gender == Gender.female:
            return 'Hello, girl.'
        else:
            return 'Hey there, user!'
```

This still won't work for multiple selections, though.