# non-edit choicefield in django forms

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x, django-forms

```
 STATUS = (
    (1, "one"),
    (2, "first"),
    (3, "third")
)
```

I want to display in form one/first/third

```
status = forms.ChoiceField(label="Статус", choices=STATUS, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'readonly'}))
```

But this line display me 1/2/3.
How I can show the second value?

Comment: Your tuple of tuples is called `STATUS` while you are using `CONTRACTOR_STATUS` in your model field.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025733/django-model-choices

Comment: @IanAuld edit. it was mistake when I write question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776333/django-choices-for-models

Comment: @Kevin: Don't you want to use `Select` as your widget? `TextInput` won't give you the right display for `ChoiceField`, right?

Comment: @ShangWang In model I have integerfield. But in forms I only want to show active value without select

Comment: @ShangWang Thanks. You will help me